# jquery dynamic for each loop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, foreach

I have a table that has several tables in it for multiple users. These users can increase or decrease overtime, so I am trying to make it as dynamic as possible. I will attach two sample tables so you get the idea.

```
<div class="timecard">
 <h3>tommytest</h3>

<table class="misc_items timecard_list" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="display_row odd">
            <td align="left" class="job_code" style="color:#000099">2400-Orchard</td>
            <td align="right">9:47am</td>
            <td align="right">5/19/2014</td>
            <td align="right" class="hrs">01:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="display_odd row">
            <td align="left" class="job_code" style="color:#000099">1200-Duffy's</td>
            <td align="right">12:37am</td>
            <td align="right">5/17/2014</td>
            <td align="right" class="hrs">2:00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="timecard">
 <h3>testtest</h3>

<table class="misc_items timecard_list" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="display_row odd">
            <td align="left" class="job_code" style="color:#000099">2400-Orchard</td>
            <td align="right">9:47am</td>
            <td align="right">5/19/2014</td>
            <td align="right" class="hrs">01:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="display_odd row">
            <td align="left" class="job_code" style="color:#000099">1200-Duffy's</td>
            <td align="right">12:37am</td>
            <td align="right">5/17/2014</td>
            <td align="right" class="hrs">2:00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="total"></div>
```

I then have a jQuery script run through the table and then calculate the total of each individual job_code and display it underneath the table so that it looks like this:

```
job_code 1 = 2 hours
job_code 2 = 4 hours
```

I am having trouble making my below javascript calculate the first table, display the results, then move on to the next table and do the same thing. So on and so forth.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var timeString = $(this).next('td.hrs').text();
var components = timeString.split(':');
var seconds = components[1] ? parseInt(components[1], 10) : 0;
var hrs = parseInt(components[0], 10) + seconds / 60;
total += hrs;

var temp = [];
$('.job_code').each(function (index, element) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (text != 'Out') {
        temp.push(text);
    }
});

// remove duplicates
var job_code = [];
$.each(temp, function (index, element) {
    if ($.inArray(element, job_code) === -1) job_code.push(element);
});

var sum = {};
$.each(job_code, function (index, element) {
    var total = 0;
    $('.job_code:contains(' + element + ')').each(function (key, value) {
        var timeString = $(this).siblings('td.hrs').text();
        var components = timeString.split(':');
        var seconds = components[1] ? parseInt(components[1], 10) : 0;
        var hrs = parseInt(components[0], 10) + seconds / 60;
        total += hrs;
        sum[index] = {
            'job_code': element,
                'total': total
        };
    });
});

console.log(sum);

$.each(sum, function (index, element) {
    $('#total').append('<p>Total for ' + element.job_code + ': ' + element.total + '</p>');
});

});
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I am just starting to use javascript and am quickly reaching the end of my capabilities. Here is a link to a sample [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ugcG/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all why not to make any calculations before formatting and layout generation? I would be much easier.

Anyway if you want to iterate tables then iterate some data in it, try to use something like this:

```
$('.timecard_list').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.job_code').each(function() {
    ...
  });
});
```

Comment: that didn't work. It just displays more totals under the last table.

Comment: Then I can't understand exactly what do you need.

Comment: I may have entered it in the wrong place then. Can you make a sample jsfiddle?